# Creating square tick box in exam

Tags: exam, box

Like title, I want to create square box like this but \checkboxes in exam just create circle. Can anyone help me T.T

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{exam} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\checkboxchar{$\Box$}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Question 1:} 
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice $1$
            \choice $2$
        \end{checkboxes}
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice $3$
            \choice $4$
        \end{checkboxes}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We cry with you as we don't know what you are doing exactly and it is therefore very hard to answer this. It would be great if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you tried and the context in which you want this to work.

Comment: If you use the `exam` class, it is probably helpful to look into the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf). As suggested there, you could try placing `\checkboxchar{$\Box$}` in your preamble (`\usepackage{amssymb}` is also needed).

Comment: @JasperHabicht Can I increase the size of the square made by \checkboxchar{$\Box$} ? It isn't big as the one in the picture.

Comment: Please show your code. It is not really efficient to talk in the comments. You should be able to use the basic commands to change font sizes, such as `\large`, but take care to create a scope by wrapping everything in curly brackets.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I just upload my code. But the size of the square is a bit small. Can you recommend a way to make it bigger ?

Comment: Scalebox can help

Comment: @tobiasBora how to use scalebox, can u give an example pls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for providing a nice MWE! You can use the `\checkboxchar` command to change the appearance of the boxes as well as to specify the size of the box using basic commands to alter font size and to shift it up or down using `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{exam} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\checkboxchar{\raisebox{-.2em}{\Large$\Box$}}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Question 1:} 
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice $1$
            \choice $2$
        \end{checkboxes}
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice $3$
            \choice $4$
        \end{checkboxes}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]